# PHP: class not found even with using namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to execute a php script with ajax but I get this error `Fatal error: Class 'backoffice\controllers\TypesManager' not found` although I used namespace.
This is the php file that I called it from ajax function:

```
namespace backoffice\controllers;
use backoffice\controllers\TypesManager;

$tm = new TypesManager();
echo $tm->getAllTypes();
```

And this is the my `TypesManager` class:

```
namespace backoffice\controllers;


/**
 * TypesManager
 */
class TypesManager{

    function __construct(){

    }

    public function getAllTypes(){
        echo 'Display all types.';
    }
}
```

Both classes are under this path: `backoffice/controller.`
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Are you using any framework? if not do you have autoloader which loads this class for you?

Comment: What autoloader are you using? And how are you calling that code via ajax? If you are just making a request directly to that file, then your autoloader wont be loaded. Generally in modern OOP frameworks, all requests get routed via a frontcontroller

Comment: hmm actualy I thought this is SPL fonctionalities I'm not using any framework or autoloader.

Comment: Use of autoloading classes requires registering you autoload function

Comment: Just try to remove your `use backoffice\controllers\TypesManager;` since you've already declared namespace

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to use autoloader, can u give any example ? thnx.

Comment: refer this http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/

Comment: @SagarGuhe Thnx alot :)

Comment: @SlimenTunis you are most welcome :)