# PHP: autoload can't find JsonSerializable

Tags: php, autoload

I use JsonSerializable for my entities to convert them to json array like this:

```
namespace backoffice\entities;

class MyObject implements \JsonSerializable{
   //---do some stuff---
}
```

and then I use my Autoloader.php to load classes by namespace:

```
/**
 * Class Autoloader
 */

class Autoloader{
    static function register(){

        spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__, 'autoload'));
    }

    static function autoload($className){
        $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
        require_once $className.'.php';     
    }

}
```

In the `autoload` function I replace the `\\` with directory_separator of the server.
The autoloader load my classes without problems but when he comes to JsonSerializable (which is an SPL interface) convert the `\\` and load it from my namespace (where he will not find it) and shows me this error:

```
Warning: require_once(backoffice/entities/JsonSerializable.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How to make it work properly and load this interface from SPL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: autoloader can't find the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503257/php-autoloader-cant-find-the-file)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own querstions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503257/php-autoloader-cant-find-the-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268022/php-class-not-found-even-with-using-namespace . Please fix that autoloader and stop reposting the same questioon over and over again.

Comment: @maxhb I did fixed it, now the autoload loads my entities correctly but still gives me the error I wrote above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
It was a PHP version problem, JsonSerializable requires PHP 5.4 and the server online uses PHP 5.3 so that's why he can't find it, and it worked on localhost because I'm using PHP 5.5